# Retrieving Azure Service Principle Certificate

Tags: powershell, azure, ssl, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to retrieve the certificate for an Azure Active Directory Service Principle after it has been created?

I have found how to [create a Service Principle using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal) but haven't been able to find if it's possible to retrieve the cert from the portal, or by SDK or Script.

Answer (score 1):

Use get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0

```
PS C:\Users\maweeras> Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -ObjectId $ServicePrincipalId.ObjectId -ReturnKeyValues $true


Type      : Asymmetric
Value     :
KeyId     : 893295bf-f682-4682-a1d6-106508f41432
StartDate : 20/10/2016 21:56:16
EndDate   : 20/10/2018 21:56:16
Usage     : Sign

Type      : Password
Value     :
KeyId     : 893295bf-f682-4682-a1d6-106508f41432
StartDate : 20/10/2016 21:56:16
EndDate   : 20/10/2018 21:56:16
Usage     : Sign

Type      : Asymmetric
Value     : MIIC8DCCAdigAwIBAgIQK<snipped for brevity>E/Ce59c7EJAEjbtvyXiwRLvy07SMZgLBbrpBSOc9f2RaSZlQEmzagNEoDZnXHRYCIVlD7DN7Xdf96iGja4
            pwoZaRz6TW618EIQAh+jAuUcOxInGJErrHZjMjaFmWSsH
KeyId     : 3ee9318e-b35a-48a8-b24c-5311d076e9e3
StartDate : 20/10/2016 21:56:16
EndDate   : 20/10/2018 21:56:16
Usage     : Verify

Type      : Other
Value     :
KeyId     :
StartDate :
EndDate   :
Usage     :
```

Comment: I would mark this as answered, but the MSOnline module has been deprecated in favor of the AzureAD module. [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0)  

But this did get me started on the right path. Thank you!